# Does only distributed systems follow CAP theorem?

Tags: distributed-system, cap-theorem

I have read somewhere on the internet that the theorem is a set of basic requirements that describe any distributed system. Please help me in understanding that is the theorem only applicable to the distributed systems?

Answer (score 3):

It applies to any system that relies on **message passing** for communication instead of, say, shared memory.

For most people, that means any system that **communicates over a network**. For many website architectures, the CAP theorem trade-offs drive the which-database-to-use decision. For example, choosing between using a big MySQL database vs DynamoDB vs all things in between.